# POST запрос в андроид приложении

Tags: android, post, регистрация

Реализую регистрацию, но не имею понятия как это прописать. С post запросами столкнулся впервые, до этого писал для get. Есть мысли, что нужно сначала передать строки в json и только потом на сервер. Подправьте меня, если ошибаюсь.

Решил попробовать библиотеку Retrofit, но приложение упало.
Вот код

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    private static final String TAG = "this";
    private final String baseUrl = "http://u1938.blue.elastictech.org/api/users";

    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();

    private Link parse = (Link) retrofit.create(List.class);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getExtras();

        buttonRegistration2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (editPassword != editPassword2) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Пароли не совпадают. Повторите попытку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Map<String, String> mapJson = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    mapJson.put("email", editEmail.getText().toString());
                    mapJson.put("name", editUserName.getText().toString());
                    mapJson.put("password", editPassword.getText().toString());
                    mapJson.put("contact_number", editNumber.getText().toString());

                    Call<Object> call = parse.parseMethod(mapJson);

                    try {
                        Response<Object> response = call.execute();
                        Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);

                        for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet())
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.getKey() + "" + e.getValue());
                            Log.e(TAG, "Object");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Интерфейс

```
interface Link {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/users")
    Call<Object> parseMethod(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map);
}
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idrisov.mypost/com.example.idrisov.mypost.RegistrationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
```

Comment: В нынешнем андроиде нужны большие танцы с бубнами чтобы обойти запрет на отправку на http адрес. Пробуй отправлять на https.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую посмотреть про POST набрав в интернете "java POST".

Видеоурок по JSON:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Almffj2Gms

Еще тебе понадобится установка сторонних библиотек. Точно не помню как, но зайдя в Gradle Script > build.gradle(Module:app) добавь библиотеку можно с помощью (моя "внешняя библиотека" находится на уровне корня проекта. Поэтому путь к файлу будет разный):

`implementation files('../../../библиотека.jar')`

Вот пример программы на которой я учился (может есть и лучше варианты):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades?pair=XXBTZEUR&since=0";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTCZUSD";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "{\"pair\":{\"XBTEUR\"}";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://square.github.io/retrofit/ попробуйте использовать эту библиотеку
пример интерфейса

```
 @POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```